Creating a Debian sid chroot on Ubuntu 22.04
From my Debian/stable system I can simply create a chroot for some playground like this:
% cd /tmp
% sudo debootstrap sid ./sid-chroot http://deb.debian.org/debian   
[...]
I: Configuring libc-bin...
I: Base system installed successfully.

However here is what I see on my Ubuntu system:
% cd /tmp
% sudo rm -rf sid-chroot
% sudo debootstrap sid ./sid-chroot http://deb.debian.org/debian        
I: Retrieving InRelease
I: Checking Release signature
I: Valid Release signature (key id A7236886F3CCCAAD148A27F80E98404D386FA1D9)
[...]
I: Validating zlib1g 1:1.3.dfsg+really1.3.1-1
I: Chosen extractor for .deb packages: dpkg-deb
I: Extracting apt...
I: Extracting base-files...
E: Tried to extract package, but file already exists. Exit...

I failed to understand what this error message mean ? What did I do wrong ?
For reference:
% cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"


It means a file that you are extracting already exists. This is a clear error message, You do know that Debian and Ubuntu are not the same thing. It appears you can not simply do the exact same thing in Ubuntu. You have failed to include in your question the exact version of Ubuntu you are working with. Please edit the question and add this critical info.

debootstrap is currently bugged on Jammy (22.04):
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/base-files/+bug/2054925
Force the installation of this version using dpkg -i and it should work. You can use the following commands from your ~ directory:
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/debootstrap/debootstrap_1.0.134ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i ./debootstrap_1.0.134ubuntu1_all.deb

